# How to export schema for the existing table through WebUI in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to take the export schema for the existing table through WebUI and recreate a new table with the same structure in BigQuery.

I could not find ways to export schema in WebUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I'd do it is first create a query with the data that you want, for instance:

```
SELECT 
  fullvisitorid,
  visitid
FROM `dataset.ga_sessions_20170703`
LIMIT 1
```

And bring just one result. In the `Show Options` button, you can choose the destination of the results to be another table:

[image]

[image]

After that, you can remove the 1 row you have in your new table using [DML syntax](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax):

```
DELETE FROM `new_table`
WHERE fullvisitorid = '1'
```

The result is a new empty table with the desired schema from other table.

Comment: Okay, Will. Does the datatype of the new table will be same as the existing table or it depends on the output row of the select query?

Comment: if you cast it to some other type then it will change in the new table. If you just select the row then it should be just the same.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, Will . It helps. From your answers I understand that currently there is no way to export schema for the existing table through UI in Bigquery. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: That's right, the only other way would be to create the table manually and them build its schema in the WebUI. For what I understand from the question, you want to have this process a bit more automated.

Comment: Exactly. I am looking for some automation here and I need different table names of same structure. In future I may need to add a new field to all the columns if I need to store some more info in the tables.